# Can I expect some income from "utility" websites?

Tags: google-adsense, revenue

There are quite a few one-page-only websites that are made to perform a simple/single task. Examples of such websites include:

- http://dummyimage.com/ -- generates a dummy image
- http://www.lipsum.com/ -- generates lipsum text
- http://ajaxload.info/ -- generates animated ajax loading images
- http://www.generatedata.com/ -- generates dummy data for sql
- http://jsbeautifier.org/ -- formats your javascript
- http://jsonlint.com/ -- validates JSON
- http://yui.2clics.net/ -- online YUI compressor
- http://www.colorpicker.com/ -- online color picker

Very few of these websites show an advertisements. Now I have a few ideas of my own and I was wondering if these websites have some way of earning income to keep them up and running.

Should I expect to earn some income if I set up a few websites such as these?

Should I setup AdSense on my (planned) website? My ideas are not absolutely unique but rare.

Answer (score 8):

Ads are one way to benefit from providing these types of services, but there's often also a self-promotional aspect.

Offer a small but useful tool that many people link to, include a link back to your portfolio site(check; they almost all do), and some of that traffic will filter down to you, almost as a matter of fact("What else has this person built that I might like?"). This will also have some search benefits. So, you may not get income *directly* from the utility sites, but then again you might end up with a client or two.

[This is in addition to what @Anagio said; just another facet.]

Comment: This is a good point

Answer (score 3):

If you can provide a unique service like the websites you listed above, and it begins to receive traffic you should expect to be able to monetize the site. But the overall content on these sites is the service and content they offer. The advertisements are not the main focus.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the lipsum website carried a "advertise here" banner for a good 9 months before someone took an add out on there. I would say that any income you generate would be small. But, it's something!